# Is unowned logically equivalent to weak! in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, automatic-ref-counting

Will these blocks always fail under the same circumstances (when the closure is being executed but self was deallocated)?

```
{ [unowned self] in
    //use self
    self.number = self.number + 1
}

{ [weak self] in
    //use self!
    self!.number = self!.number + 1
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you get crash, while executing this code ?

Comment: Yes, if self has been deallocated. I'm asking whether both blocks will always behave the same logically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unowned reference does not keep strong reference to the self, but it makes an assumption that the object always has some value (is not nil) and if, some how self deallocates while executing the block, the above code crashes.

For the case of weak, as in your example, weak is an optional type inside the block, so there could also be a value or it could be nil. It is your responsibility to check if the value exists and call methods on it. As above if you use unwrapping operator (!), when self has been deallocated, then it surely crashes. So, both the version of the code crashes, if it happens such that the block is still executing and self is deallocated in the mean time.

So, I suggest to use weak to safeguard such crashes using the optional checks,

```
{ [weak self] in
    if let me = self {
       me.number = me.number + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: "and if, some how self deallocates while executing the block" or before the block executes

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those are equivalent. That is the point of `unowned` -- it's just like `weak`, except that you don't have to deal with an optional and unwrap it, because its type is the unwrapped non-optional type; it is `weak` that is always forcibly unwrapped at every appearance.

Comment: although `unowned` is unsafe - it will crash if `self` is deallocated.

Comment: @AaronBrager: No more "unsafe" than force-unwrapping. The question is if they are the same. If it was `weak`, and the object is deallocated, the value will be `nil`. And force-unwrapping an optional with value `nil` will crash.

Answer (score 1):

Should use it like this

```
{ [weak self] in

    guard let weakSelf = self else {
       return 
    }

    weakSelf.number = weakSelf.number + 1
}
```

---

Thanks to **@José**'s comment, be aware that even though the following code works at the moment, but it is considered a compiler bug and should be avoided https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160118/007425.html.

You can also unwrap `self` like this:

```
{ [weak self] in

    guard let `self` = self else {
       return 
    }

    // Now you can use `self` safely
    self.number = self.number + 1
}
```

Comment: This is a compiler bug though and should be avoided: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160118/007425.html

Comment: @José thanks for pointing this out! I will add a note in the post so that everyone knows!